# Android Image Slider by Daimajia not working in a Fragment but works when not in a Fragment

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, slider

I am trying to implement an Image flipper from a github library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider .At first when I tried the code in an activity without any fragment it was working fine but when I tried putting it in a fragment it doesnt work and the screen becomes blank.

Here is the code in the fragment-

```
    public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener{

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FragmentB newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);
        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
        HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        file_maps.put("Hannibal",R.drawable.hannibal);
        file_maps.put("Big Bang Theory",R.drawable.bigbang);
        file_maps.put("House of Cards",R.drawable.house);
        file_maps.put("Game of Thrones", R.drawable.game_of_thrones);
        for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getContext());
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit) .setOnSliderClickListener(this)
            ;

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Here is the code in an Activity which is functioning -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener{
    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);


        HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        file_maps.put("Hannibal",R.drawable.hannibal);
        file_maps.put("Big Bang Theory",R.drawable.bigbang);
        file_maps.put("House of Cards",R.drawable.house);
        file_maps.put("Game of Thrones", R.drawable.game_of_thrones);

        for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit) .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() { mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
        Toast.makeText(this,slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

This is the XML code-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.abhay.voley_tab_sqlite.Fragments_Tabs_Home.FragmentB">


<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    custom:pager_animation="FlipHorizontal"
    custom:auto_cycle="true"
    custom:indicator_visibility="invisible"
    custom:pager_animation_span="700"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

I have tried making the 'false' parameter in the inflater to 'true', yet no results.Please help.

Comment: any solution you found bro??? for me problem is coming in android 4.4 and lesser version with Fragment..

Comment: @Prakash see my solution. is this working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is little late but anyone who is still facing this issue can solve it..

[AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) is only compatible with **Picasso version 2.3.2**

So in your gradle dependencies change picasso to this version

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    }
```

I have tested it. Working for me !!

Answer (score 0):

AndroidImageSLider doesn't only compatible with Picasso version 2.3.2. You can also use with Glide. Here is example

```
public class GlideSliderView extends DefaultSliderView {
    public GlideSliderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    protected void bindEventAndShow(final View v, ImageView targetImageView) {
         Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(getUrl())
            .into(targetImageView);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Image Slider by Daimajia Library is already compatible with the latest version. Just set up your Picasso. So just add these lines with textSliderview

**Java:**
textSliderView.setPicasso(Picasso.get());

**Kotlin:**
textSliderView.picasso = Picasso.get()